# Trying to find out total no of votes, but could not understand how it is done in serializers. I'm new to django, How is it done?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here is my model :

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="", blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    upVotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downVotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    votes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_votes', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('id', 'question', 'answer', 'author', 'createdAt', 'votes')

    def get_votes(self, obj):
        if obj.upVotes and obj.downVotes:
            total_votes = (obj.upVotes + obj.downVotes)
            return total_votes
```

Here is my upVote view :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def upvote(request, pk):
    answer = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=pk)
    author=request.user
    voter = upVote.objects.filter(author=author, answer=answer)        
    if voter.exists():
        return Response({
            'details':'You cannot vote twice'
        })
    else:
        upVote.objects.create(
            answer=answer,
            author=author
        )
        answer.upVotes += 1
        answer.save()
        return Response({
            'details':'Vote added'
        })
```

How to find total number of votes and that should be directed to answers model. How to do this kind of operations in serializers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_votes(self, obj):
    total_votes = 0
    if obj.upVotes is not None and obj.downVotes is not None:
        total_votes = (obj.upVotes + obj.downVotes)
        return total_votes
```

thats happening because either upvote or downvote is none.
you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating the get_votes view accordingly

```
def upvote(request, pk):
   answer = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=pk)
   author = request.user
   voter = upVote.objects.filter(author=author, answer=answer)

   if voter.exists():
       return Response({'details': 'You cannot vote twice'})
   else:
       upVote.objects.create(answer=answer, author=author)
       answer.upVotes += 1
       answer.save()

    
       total_votes = answer.upVotes + answer.downVotes

       return Response({'details': 'Vote added', 'total_votes': total_votes})
```

After you increment the upVotes and save the answer object, you calculate the total votes by summing the upVotes and downVotes fields directly in the view. Then, you return the total_votes in the response